# Pasar variables entre hojas php

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas noches, me encuentro realizando un cajero automatico en php con mysql y tengo la siguiente duda:

utilice el sistema de usuario y contraseña de agustin ramos (en internet lo puedes buscar)

el cual trabaja de la siguiente manera:

Tienes el entrar.php donde te sale para meter el usuario y la contraseña

luego el action de ese formulario es llamado login y posee todas las comparaciones para verificar que existan en la base de datos

luego te envia al home donde tenes las opciones de conectado

yo tengo en mi caso en vez de la tabla usuario con user y contrseña tengo asociada la tabla tarjeta y te pide numero de tarjeta y codigo de tarjeta

yo quisiera entonces que:

ese numero de tarjeta (num_tar) se guardara en una variable y que llegara hasta home.php para luego usarla, pense en colocarla en el login.php(donde estan las funciones) pero me sale en home.php no definida.

AQUI LOS CODIGOS DEL LOGIN.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
if(isset($_POST["num_tar"]) &&isset($_POST["cod_tar"])){
    if($_POST["num_tar"]!=""&&$_POST["cod_tar"]!=""){
        include "conexion.php";

        $user_id=null;
        $sql1= "select * from tarjeta where (num_tar=\"$_POST[num_tar]\" and cod_tar=\"$_POST[cod_tar]\")";
        $query = $con->query($sql1);
        while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
            $user_id=$r["num_tar"];
            break;
        }
        if($user_id==null){
            print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido.\");window.location='../index.php';</script>";
        }else{
            session_start();
```

AQUI TRATE DE PASARLO PERO NO GUARDA

```
            global $num;
            $num=$_POST['num_tar'];
            $_SESSION["conectado"]=$user_id;

            print "<script>window.location='../home.php';</script>";                
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

creo que el problema esta en que el sistema tendria que pasarlo a login.php primero y luego a home.php pero en home.php me salen no declaradas las variables

Comment: coloque esto en el login.php
session_start();
     $_SESSION["conectado"]=$user_id;
     $num=$_POST["num_tar"];
    print "<script>window.location='../home.php?usuario=$num';</script>";

y ahora lo pasa a home y lo recibo asi:

 <?php 
   
   $datos  = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
   echo $datos;
   $num=$datos;
   ?>

y lo paso a consulta asi:

<input type ='button' class="letra3" value ='1' onclick="window.top.location.href = 'consulta.php?usuario=$num';"/> 

y lo recibo asi;

 <?php $datos   = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
   echo $datos;
   ?>
 
pero me sale el valor como "$num"

Comment: lo solucione con esto <?=$_REQUEST['usuario']?>

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor sería enviarlo como variable de sesión, es decir, pasarlo por el formulario hasta login.php, si el login es correcto se inicia la sesión con `session_start();` y se envía ese valor como variable de sesión así: `$_SESSION['nameKey']=value`.

Entonces cada vez que inicies sesión con `session_start();` podrás obtener esa variable, sin importar el archivo php en el que te encuentres.

Answer (score 1):

Como te mencionan arriba lo que mejor que puedes hacer es usarlo como variable de sesión, pero que le asignes un nombre a la sesión session_start("nombre_de_la_sesion"); Esto lo puedes poner en tu archivo de funciones al inicio y lo incluyes normal.

Le asignas un valor a la variable $_SESSION["nombre_de_la_variable"] = valor; cada que quieras hacer referencia a esa variable lo haces directo o pasas el valor a otra.

echo $_SESSION["nombre_de_la_variable"];

$variable = $_SESSION["nombre_de_la_variable"];
echo $variable;

Cuando ya no necesites usar la información solamente usas unset($_SESSION["nombre_de_la_variable"]); para destruir solo la variable o session_destroy(); y se destruye todo el contenido de la sesión